# Is there a way to use a server serial (com) port as a client to connect to a switch console?

Tags: serial

I'm trying to connect an IBM idataplex 360 M4 node via it's front rs232 port to the console port of a switch with the switch's supplied cable, but I'm having no luck.

The server is running RHEL 6.5 x64.

Switch manual claim the connection should be 9600 8N1 no flow control.
minicom, picocom, screen, putty, gtkterm all fail (blank screen, no echo whatsoever).

I suspect the issue might be due to the bios configuration of the port, as the server can set serial redirection, port sharing, SOL and other goodies which are usually meant to be used the other way around - when connecting from a serial client to the server, not when using the server as a client - but I don't really know.

The switch was previously accessed from a laptop serial port.

EDIT:
OS sees two ports: ttyS0, ttyS1. result the same on both.